# initial array in size by ref c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, byref

I was asked to create this function:

```cpp
int * createAndInput(int & size)
```

The function initializes an array in the size of
the value `size`, gets the values from the user as input, and returns the allocated array and the size by ref.

Here is the code I have so far:

```cpp
int *creatAndInput(int& size)
{ 
    int arr1[***size***];
    for (int i = 0; i << size; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter index " << (i + 1) << endl;
        cin >> arr1[i]; 
    }
    return (arr1);
}

void main()
{
    cout << "enter size number" << endl;
    int size2 = 10;
    int *size1 = &size2;
    cout << *creatAndInput(size2);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question but not as image.

Comment: Change `i << size` to `i < size`.

Comment: You need to use `new[]` to allocate the array, or use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int* createAndInput(int& size)
{
    int* ptr = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << i+1 << ". element: ";
        std::cin >> ptr[i];
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main(){

    int *ptr, size;

    std::cout << "Size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    ptr = createAndInput(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << i+1 << ". element: "<< ptr[i] << std::endl;

    delete[] ptr;

    return 0;
}
```